# Error: Neither the Property…Nor one of the Methods…exists and have public access

Tags: php, symfony4

I keep getting the following error after save data in the form, when i enter the line 9 in "create.html.twig":

> Neither the property "category" nor one of the methods "category()",
>   "getcategory()"/"iscategory()"/"hascategory()" or "__call()" exist and
>   have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

### Create.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} 
{% form_theme formArticle 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

    <h1>Création d'un article</h1>
    {{ form_start(formArticle) }}

    {{ form_row(formArticle.title, {'attr': {'placeholder':"Titre de l'article"}}) }}
    {{ form_row(formArticle.category.title) }}
    {{ form_row(formArticle.content, {'attr': {'placeholder':"Contenu de l'article"}}) }}
    {{ form_row(formArticle.image, {'attr': {'placeholder':"Url de l'article"}}) }}


    <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-succes primary">
        {% if editMode %}
        Enrengistrer les modifications
        {% else %}
            Ajouter l'article
        {% endif %}    

    </button>

    {{ form_end(formArticle) }}

{% endblock %}

    ~
```

### Article.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */

class Article

{ /**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\Length(min=10, max=255, minMessage="Votre titre est trop court")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min=10, minMessage="Votre article doit faire minimum 10 mots")
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\Url()
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()

    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getTitle(): ?string

    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self

    {
         $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string

    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self

    {
         $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

      public function getImage(): ?string

    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self

    {
         $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }      


    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface

    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self

    {
         $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comment[]
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments[] = $comment;
            $comment->setArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if ($this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getArticle() === $this) {
                $comment->setArticle(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }      

}
```

### ArticleType

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',

            ])
            ->add('content')
            ->add('image')
            ->add('createdAt')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Article::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

### Category.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Article[]
     */
    public function getArticles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }

    public function addArticle(Article $article): self
    {
        if (!$this->articles->contains($article)) {
            $this->articles[] = $article;
            $article->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArticle(Article $article): self
    {
        if ($this->articles->contains($article)) {
            $this->articles->removeElement($article);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($article->getCategory() === $this) {
                $article->setCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I come across the error only when I put the line 9 `{{form_row (formArticle.category.title)}}`. When I remove the line the form is good and I do not encounter any problem.

Comment: The error is in the `FormView`, you are not dealing with the article *entity* anymore but with the form *field*. You've already defined the label in the type, just use `formArticle.category`.

Comment: Thank for your answer but i always have the same mistake while I changed the line by "{{ form_row(formArticle.category) }}"

Comment: Maybe try to [clear the cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache)?

Comment: I tried that but it did not work :(

Comment: @YacineSoussi I tried your code (only with `title` and `category` properties) making the changes suggested in my previous comment and works for me. If you have a stack trace, [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: What do you advise me to add in the title. I start developing and I do not know what exactly is it stack trace

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from the ArticleType file on the line :

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
])
```

At this moment you instantiate a new object category who try to call a method getCategory, and as you can see in your entity there is no method getCategory in the entity category

from my point of view you should try something like that :

```
->add('Category', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\Category',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('q');
                    }
```

nothing to do in your entities files

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately the error persists anyway. If it helps the error is "RunTimeError"

Comment: Could you give me more informations about runtime error ? full message

Comment: here is the error screen https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/35/4/1567096060-neithertheproperty.png